# I want to access the values of an object to Laravel Blade file from Controller

Tags: php, laravel, static, laravel-blade

Here is my code. I am trying to access the `bookName` and `bookAuthor`. But the variables are set in static. I don't want to change this to public. But I want to access those values. How can I do it?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Book
{
    private $bookName;
    private $bookAuthor;

    public function __construct($name, $author)
    {
        $this->bookName = $name;
        $this->bookAuthor = $author;
    }
    public function getNameAndAuthor()
    {
        return $this->bookName . ' - ' . $this->bookAuthor;
    }
}
class BookFactory
{
    public static function create($name, $author)
    {
        return new Book($name, $author);
    }
}

class FactoryController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $book1 = BookFactory::create('Laravel', 'Imrul');
        $book2 = BookFactory::create('ReactJS', 'Hasan');

        $book1->getNameAndAuthor();
        $book2->getNameAndAuthor();
        // dump($book1);
        // dd($book1);
        return view('home', compact(['book1', 'book2']));
    }
}
```

`home.blade.php`

```
<h3>{{ $book1->bookName }}</h3>
<h3>{{ $book1->bookAuthor }}</h3>
```

Comment: make a model, it will be easier, you are trying to access the aributes of a model and actually what you want to access is your variables: bookName, bookName.
If you try to access the attributes of your model from the tee controller does it show anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you create a model: php artisan make:model Book -a, wiht -a will create you migration and controller apart from the model.

in your migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('author');
        $table->string('title');
    });
}
```

On your model:

```
class Book extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'books';

   protected $fillable = [
   'author', 'title'
];


}
```

On your controller:

```
public function create()
{
    $book1 = Book::create([
        'author' => 'Henry',
        'title' => 'Smith',
    ]);
    $book2 = Book::create([
        'author' => 'Antony',
        'title' => 'Gjj',
    ]);
    return view('home', compact(['book1', 'book2']));

}
```

On your blade:

```
 <h3>{{ $book1->title }}</h3>
 <h3>{{ $book1->author }}</h3>
```

Comment: Thanks Bro for your support .... This error come  `Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Trying to get property 'title' of non-object (View: E:\github\Design Patterns\Design-Patterns\resources\views\home.blade.php)`

Answer (score 0):

```
class Book
{
    private $bookName;
    private $bookAuthor;

public function __construct($name, $author)
{
    $this->bookName = $name;
    $this->bookAuthor = $author;
}
public function getNameAndAuthor()
{
    return $this->bookName . ' - ' . $this->bookAuthor;
}

 public function getBookNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->bookName;
    }
 public function getBookAuthorAttribute()
    {
        return  $this->bookAuthor;
    }

}
```

now your code in blade should work:

```
<h3>{{ $book1->bookName }}</h3>
<h3>{{ $book1->bookAuthor }}</h3>
```